# Trouble in hosting WCF Service in IIS 5.1

Tags: wcf

I am having trouble hosting a simple WCF service application in IIS 5.1 (XP SP3).

I follow this Pluralsight tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVPXLF-g4Ws) but still the service won't load and shows IE blank page "You are not authorized to view this page .. HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden "

any advice? how to host WCF service in IIS 5.1.

Comment: where can I modify the Authentication of IIS?

Comment: I see, the Authentication is already set to Anonymous access.

Comment: I tried adding the ASPNET user on the security option of the service folder, but now when i browse the WCF website, it display nothing as in pure white page.,..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the IIS Authentication for your IIS host website to "Anonymous" and see if that is where your problem is and if doing this makes it work.

[image]

NOTE: In reality, you will need to set your authentication in IIS based on whatever your authentication method is going to be.

Comment: exactly the same as mine, I even add the ASPNET user on security tab of the service folder but to no avail...

Comment: oh. after i configured it, it now displays nothing.. blank white page even the other asp websites..

Comment: no, actually the WCf website folder resides on another website, i changed both.. even if I add new virtual directory, it also displays ou are not authorized to view this page .. HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden, i think i messed the configuration of my IIS

Comment: @csharpnoob - yup..i think so too. However i must add that these settings work fine normally. I have a host of WCF services all accessible with these very settings on my PC. If you have nested virtual directories, that may be messing it up depending on what the config for the parent folders may be! Check that out. As long as you have the above settings, you should not get forbidden. Remember to do IISRESET afte making changes!

Comment: I got it now running, but its wierd, when i try to browse it on IIS it displays nothing, but when I manually browse it like this on the ie browser http: //localhost/DLService/PhysicianService.svc, it does show, even the other websites...

Comment: That is a bit weird! Havent seen something like that happen before. Well as long as it works in the browser and hopefully from your client app, thats the main thing! :-)